# What is the art gallery where Fred and Leo meet in Humans 1.7?

Tags: film-location, humans

In episode 7, season 1, of [Humans](http://www.amc.com/shows/humans), Leo and Fred meet in an unusual art gallery:

[image]

What gallery is it and where is it located?

Comment: I just watched this episode a week ago and was curious about the location. But it took your question to spur me into finding where it was filmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Marianne North Gallery](http://www.kew.org/visit-kew-gardens/explore/attractions/marianne-north-gallery) of the Royal Botanical Gardens at Kew. The museum is located in at Kew Park in south-west London, UK. 
It was built in the 1880's to house the 833 paintings of Marianne North.

Here is a picture from the museum's website. You can see that the floor and the walls match the image from the show.

[image: Marianne North Gallery]

Another image from [this website](http://www.planetware.com/london/kew-gardens-royal-botanic-gardens-eng-sr-kg.htm) is larger.
[image]

> Opened in 1882, the Marianne North Gallery pays homage to the artist after which this massive collection is named. The daughter of a politician, North travelled far and wide across North and South America, Asia and Africa in order to pursue her passion for painting plants and flowers. This stunning collection includes 832 of her paintings and is Britain's only permanent art exhibit dedicated to the career of just one woman.

Comment: That's great! How did you track that down?

Comment: A great deal of google! The final search that found it  was for "UK"+ "quaint" + "museums". I scrolled through the image results until I found a match. The 2nd image in my answer was the result I found.